# Asking to review my research paper

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, authorship

I recently wrote a research paper and want to submit it to a journal but as I wrote it on my own and it's my first paper, I would like someone (a faculty member or a PhD student) to review my paper and in exchange I offer them an authorship. How do I approach faculty members and have them do so?

Comment: Are you a student somewhere? If so, at what level?

Comment: Yes. I'm finishing the last semester of may bachelor's.

Comment: Ask one of your profs you have a good reputation with. Or do you know phd students or similar? Ask them!

Comment: giving your results for some unknown person may cause you some trouble... What is your plan if they claim it is their own results? You might be able to prove it but it is a headache.. Look for some one whom you can trust.. Btw, what is that ``sensitive" research topic?

Comment: Another way is, go to the appropriate stackexchange/overflow site and ask a question about status of your problem.. No need to tell them you have solved it.. Just post a question.. Wait for response... If it is not known already, you will get more attention.. Then, ask some one who commented on your question (look if they have good reputation, though this alone does not guarantee anything) if they want to discuss something on emai..

Comment: Now it is 2 years later (and Buffy bumped the question to the top).  Can you tell us what happened?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is pretty hard to make a blind contact and get any positive response. I suggest that your first step should be to contact a professor at your university for advice. Perhaps they are willing to do it themselves, since they have some relationship with you. But you can also ask them for advice as to who might be a good person to do it. If you don't want it done locally, say that you are looking for outside advice. Professors normally have a wide circle of contacts.

The best thing is for such a professor to make the request on your behalf rather than having you make it directly. It is harder to turn down a request from a colleague than from an unknown student.

But don't offer "authorship" for a review. Many people (most?) consider that improper. Authorship should only come if the project is not yet complete and you are seeking collaboration on finishing. If the request comes from another professor it shouldn't be expected in any case. It is just a favor that academics do for one another.

Comment: Thank you for your great advice but as my research topic is somehow sensitive, my advisor is not that willing to help me out.

Comment: It needn't be your advisor, and you don't need to ask the local professor for the review. You want external advice, I think. But the professor should be someone with whom you have a good relationship.

Comment: @Hooman  -- your comment raises *many* red flags.  If your advisor considers your research "sensitive" for any reason, and you know this it is certainly your responsibility to talk to your advisor and find out why.  It may be 100% inappropriate to publish what you're trying to publish.

Comment: @Hooman in addition to Scoutt Seidman's comment, presumably your advisor is an author of the paper (if they aren't, them not being an advisor is another red flag, since undergraduates are unlikely to be able to write research-grade papers alone). If they are an author, then they probably should be involved in writing and reviewing it.